# Concat Valuelabels with IF condition in SPSS

Tags: syntax, spss

I have 15 variables created from another question's response. If they answered the question a certain way it is a 1 otherwise it is a SYSMIS. I have another column called ValuesCount. If there is only 1 input from the 15 variables I just label ValuesCount as that variable's label. Now I need to figure out how to combine all labels if there is more than one selected. There can be 1-15 in the ValuesCount field. I think the Concat + ValueLabel is what will get the answer, but I've tried several ways of doing this, but can't seem to get it to work. This was the code I started with to play and see if I could figure it out, but no luck.

```
* Define variable labels (headers).
VARIABLE LABELS Var1 'Variable 1 label'.
VARIABLE LABELS Var2 'Variable 2 label'.

* Concatenate headers with IF statement.
COMPUTE ConcatHeaders = STRING('Variable 1: ', Var1) + IF (Var1 > 2) STRING(' (Greater than 2)') ELSE '' END IF + ', Variable 2: ' + STRING(Var2).

* Show variable labels and concatenated headers.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work with this code:

`String bought(A120).
If (SeekersMatch) bought = 'SeekersMatch'.
If (FrugalMatch) bought = CONCAT(bought, '+', 'FrugalMatch').
If (CreativesMatch) bought = CONCAT(bought, '+', 'CreativesMatch').

* Remove any leading ' + '.
IF(CHAR.INDEX(bought, ' + ') = 1) bought = REPLACE(bought, ' + ', '', 1).
EXECUTE.`

How could I get rid of the + if there is only 1 match so it doesn't say +FrugalMatch?

Comment: It is strange that the If(CHAR.INDEX... works when I tested it with the same process on another set of variables that were using the identical data, but when I deleted the variables and re-ran it it still puts a + sign in front of the bought cells if there is only 1 response???

Comment: It isn't really possible to understand you original post, please edit it and add some sample data with the expected results. Also add the additional syntax you posted in the comment to the original post - this makes it easier to understand and more useful for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following loop will create the variable you are trying to make, and solve the "+" problem at the beginning of the text:

```
String bought(A120).
String plus(A1).
do repeat vrnm=SeekersMatch FrugalMatch CreativesMatch
         /vrlb='SeekersMatch' 'FrugalMatch' 'CreativesMatch'.
   if bought<>"" plus="+".
   if vrnm bougt=concat(rtrim(bougt), plus, vrlb).
end repeat.
```

Comment: Thanks eli-k. This wasn't exactly what I needed to fix the issue, but it helped to see how to get the data fixed. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: As I said in the comment above - what you actually need is not clear enough in your question - If you clarify it more I could give a better fitting solution...